# HDMI sound works , no analog sound

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

I installed Ubuntu 12.02 and i can't hear sound, but if i connected to HDMI, I can hear sound in HDMI Device.

This is my sound device

```
~$ cat /proc/asound/cards

  0 [PCH ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
            HDA Intel PCH at 0xc2420000 irq 129

~$ aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Please give me advice to make it works

Comment: '12.02' must be a typo. If you are using 14.04, you can try to install the `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` package from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily?field.series_filter=trusty). Type `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily` and then `sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms`, then reboot.

Comment: Hie, please consider editing your question and its tags to clarify [is it ubuntu 14.04LTS, or 12.04LTS]